# Is there lsode analog in Boost OdeInt?

Tags: c++, boost, ode, odeint

There is [boost 1.53 out and OdeInt](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/getting_started/short_example.html) in it. It has a [range of numerical ode solvers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/getting_started/overview.html) in it. Yet I wonder if there is [lsode](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Ordinary-Differential-Equations.html) analog in it - for cases when you have garanteed analitical solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question. LSODE solves any generic ODE of the form dx/dt = f(x,t) [1], just like the methods in odeint. However, LSODE checks for stiffness of the problem and chooses the right scheme (predictor corrector for non-stiff, and backward differentiation for stiff problems). odeint does not provide this automatic selection, but rather relies on the user to choose the right scheme for the problem. None of the two implementations use a possible existing analytical solution, as far as I know.

[1] https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/odepack/odepack_home.html

Answer (score 0):

Most ODE solvers does imply some kind of restrictions over original LSODE (the Fortran implementation). The closest alternative I know is Octave from GNU for now.